# React native tabview configure sliding speed

Tags: animation, react-native, transition, tabview

I'm using react native tab view https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view  to have something like a carousel. It seems to work fine, but the sliding transition is too fast for me. How can I configure it? Docs say that there's a `configureTransition` callback which should return the transition configuration, but doesn't say what's that configuration and how should it look like:

```
 configureTransition - optional callback which returns a configuration for 
 the transition, return null to disable animation
```

Please, help me to find out how to configure transition speed.

Answer (score 1):

Transition spec is defined in [this](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-tab-view/blob/master/src/TabViewTransitioner.js) file.

```
  import { Animated } from 'react-native';

  _configureTransition = () => {
    return {
      timing: Animated.spring,
      tension: 300,
      friction: 100,
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TabViewAnimated
        ....
        configureTransition={this._configureTransition}
      />
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried  `{timig: Animated.timing, duration: 900, easing: Easing.inOut(Easing.ease)}` but it had no effect. What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve a slower sliding?

Comment: @TristanTzara you need to be using `TabViewPagerPan` to use it. Use the `renderPager` prop for that (`props => <TabViewPagerPan {...props} />`)